# Replace % with - in url PHP

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, htmlspecialchars, magic-quotes-gpc

Ok i have one maybe stupid question
On my website i have search options, that is input with GET metod, but when someone enter long seperated word like

I AM SOMETIMES BLANK

i got this in my url

http://www.example.com/search.php?page=1&txtPretraga=I%AM%SOMETIMES%BLANK

I dont know how to change that?
I want clean URL like this
http://www.example.com/search.php?page=1&txtPretraga=I-AM-SOMETIMES-BLANK

I want to change % with - in my ULR

Any ideas?

Comment: What is setting the `txtPretraga` value in your URL query string?  I would recommend replacing the spaces with '-' before adding it to the query string.

Comment: Thats not a very clean URL anyway... (-:

Comment: Dont worry, before it goes to query i done a double check,stip all, real escape etc, the problem is in my URL

Comment: Whatever is constructing that URL is not encoding it properly. Those should be `%20` instead of `%` if they're supposed to be representing spaces. Use [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: The correct answer will be something in RewriteRule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use str_replace in your php code:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$search_qry = "Whatever%They%Type";
$replace = str_replace($search_qry, "%", "-");
```

EDIT:
In the case of your strings - they have spaces, which show up as % in a URL, so use this before you do your $_GET

```
$search_qry = "Whatever They Type";
$replace = str_replace($search_qry, " ", "-");
```

EDIT 2
Since this is a $_GET - Javascript will have to be used to clean the string before it's sent. (using jQuery and javascript here)

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.example-input').blur(function(){
            var str = $(this).val();
            var clean_str = str.replace(" ", "-");
            $(this).val(clean_str);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This should clean the string in the input box before it's even sent through the get.
or instead of .blur, you can use $('submit-button').click(function(){...

Or, you can use the .htaccess file to do a mod rewrite. But I don't know that well enough.

Comment: No, no, not the problem in query the problem is in URL

Comment: Well, your problem is that you have spaces in the URL - so I would do a replace " " (space)  with "" (no space)

Comment: Ok, but how to do that, that sting comes from get form?

Comment: During the post of your $_GET, you want to clean their string first - replace all spaces with dashes.  If this is still not what you are looking for, I will need to see your code

Comment: Ok, i only knows when someone push submit button, it goes to another page, how to catch that before it goes to another page from main scope?

Comment: How do you pass the $_GET value?  You just have to pass a clean get variable.  You said above in your comments that you strip it, real escape, etc.  Now, you need to take that 'clean' string and clean it again.  Take that clean variable and use it with str_replace, then do the $_GET action with that

Comment: I pass it in get form to another page, the problem is not when it comes to page, i can to wih that what i want, but the problem is for me before GET goes to another page, i have to catch it :) Or maybe rewrite url?

Comment: Would you mind posting the code on how you pass your variable into your $_GET?  Is it through a <form> with a submit button?

Comment: Yes through a form, maybe this is a question for javascript?

Comment: Nope, everything should be fine with php - I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: Sorry, looking into it more, you might actually need javascript.  I was still thinking $_POST where you have time to do that.  I'll update the code anyways

Comment: Thanks mate i wrote it myself  <script type="text/javascript">
function provera() {
var x=document.forms["hsearch"]["txtPretraga"].value;
var n=str.replace(" ","-");
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got the fix for the problem :)

This is not question for PHP, it is for Javascript and i wrote this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function provera() {
var x=document.forms["hsearch"]["txtPretraga"].value;
var n=str.replace(" ","-");
}
</script>
```